# how to manage session django_session with login table sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy

I need to manage session in django to check whether user is active or non active. I use sqlalchemy ORM for login where django_session creates table with python manage.py syncdb of one django ORM,
how to check session user logged in with two table (Login Tabel of SQLAlchemy and Django_session Django ORM)

```
class Student(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'login'


    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(50))
    password = Column(String(50))
    session = Column(String,ForeignKey(Session))
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that checks if a user is logged in with SqlAlchemy:

```
def is_login_sql_alchemy(id):
   logged = ... check in sql alchemy, True or False
   return logged
```

Then in your view (assume a CBV):

```
if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
     logged_in_both = is_login_sql_alchemy(self.request.user.id)
```

In a function view just use request.user